# Page looks different in the same version of Firefox on different computer with the same system

Tags: html, css, firefox, windows-7

I asked that question before but with a little dose of irony in relation to Firefox and without any example, so my question was downvoted and I have requested to remove that.

Now I have example of my problem.
That take some time to get rid of all ASP.NET crap and make that example readable so I will really appreciate any help.

That site:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7">
        <style type="text/css">
            body {
                font-family:arial, tahoma, sans-serif;
                font-size:12px;
            }

            .riTextBox {
                border:1px solid #aeaeae;
                padding:2px 0 2px 1px;
                font:11px arial,sans-serif;
                width: 70px;
            }

            .something {
                border: 0pt none;
                height: 1px;
                width: 1px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
            <div class="WizardInput" style="width: 300px;"> 
                <div>
                    <span style="display:inline-block;width:60px;">USD $</span>
                    <span style="white-space:nowrap;"><input class="riTextBox" type="text"><input class="something" type="text"><input class="something" type="text"><input type="hidden"></span>
                    <span style="white-space:nowrap;"><input class="riTextBox" type="text"><input class="something" type="text"><input class="something" type="text"><input type="hidden"></span>
                    <span style="white-space:nowrap;"><input class="riTextBox" type="text"><input class="something" type="text"><input class="something" type="text"><input type="hidden"></span>
                </div>
            </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Looks like that on my computer:

[image: my firefox 5]

And looks like that on others computers (here my gf computer):

[image: her firefox 5]

The difference is about 1px, when I change 300px to 299px then it is crashed everywhere.

Anybody have an idea?
It is really hurtful for me, because I need to test sites at my work on Firefox.

Comment: As an additional information I wanna tell that I have already reinstall Firefox with all files removed from previous version and I have tried with portable version which should be totally independent and it is the same.

Answer (score 1):

Reset the text zoom to a standard value.

I'd also confirm that there isn't a network/linkage issue that is somehow interfering with a stylesheet.

Comment: Zoom is at standard value (it is the first thing I checked;). About second I don't really know what do you mean? Like you see there's no such thing like stylesheet in this example, just few styles in style tag, firebug doesn't show anything more, if you think about that... If not please be more specific.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a fiddle (I tried with width: 301px and it seems to work FF5):

http://jsfiddle.net/XUZSF/

It seems that it should fit:

60 + 77 + 77 + 77 ==> 291

But frankly doesn't.  It could be the way that text inputs are implemented... Not sure why you don't just use white-space:nowrap on the parent div instead?

Here's width 300 with white-space nowrap on the parent div isntead:

http://jsfiddle.net/EKGk4/

Comment: So you tried in your FF5 and it is crashed like in mine? Problem is that I'm tester, not developer, that code is not mine. But I guess this is generated from some ASP.Net controls and that's why. Developers don't see the problem because it looks great at their computers :(

Comment: Where's the difference came from? The same system, the same browser... 1px difference (in this case, I has also another case where difference is 2px).

Comment: If I had to guess it is the zero-width text inputs and their borders causing oveflow.  Or something to do with font anti-aliasing / installed fonts.  It did not work on my computer at 300px.

Comment: @mrzepa: But if you look at my second fiddle, it works regardless of the width set on the containing div.  I think this is what you should go with.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot go anywhere if my Firefox will be working like this (like I said, I'm a tester, it should work like on everyone's computers), I have also one weirder example and I will try show that when I find some time.